# highlight syntax in pre tags with highlight.js

Tags: javascript, syntax, highlight

there is a light powerful javascript code for syntax highlight here:

http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/

but this code just work with `<pre><code></code></pre>` blocks, which is my problem, i like to use just `<pre></pre>` because Chrome and Safari don't include line breaks for `<pre><code></code></pre>` when copy and past the code, but for `<pre></pre>` it's work.

there's a user guide too, but honestly i can't understand what must i do to highlight just pre tags. user guide is here:

http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/description/

Comment: The current version of chrome has no problems with line breaks in `<code>` tags. E.g. try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/x3NXY/) in chrome.

Comment: maybe you are right, but i like to use just javascript functions, but your example used jQuery, is there a way to make it in Javascript?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The current version of chrome has no problems with line breaks in `<code>` tags.
E.g. try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/x3NXY/) in chrome.

Here [a version without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/x3NXY/4/).

=== UPDATE ===

[Here an example](http://jsfiddle.net/x3NXY/6/) without the `<code>` tag.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var aCodes = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
    for (var i=0; i < aCodes.length; i++) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(aCodes[i]);
    }
};
```

Comment: i think your code must be work but there is 2 problem: in css style all class set to pre tag and second problem is i think pre tag is better than code for old browsers, can't you change your code to work with pre? :-)

Comment: still not work :-( i used your code in my index page in this way: `<script type="text/javascript">
hljs.tabReplace = '';
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
window.onload = function() {
var aCodes = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for (var i=0; i < aCodes.length; i++) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(aCodes[i]);
}
}
</script>` but highlighting did not work. sorry for bother.

Comment: Does my example work in your browser? You can remove `hljs.tabReplace = ''; hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();`, it's not needed. Can you show us the complete content of your index page?

Comment: it was just for browser caching, with a refresh finally workd! thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

I think you just need to change your initialization to:

```
$("pre").each(function (i, e) {
    hljs.highlightBlock(e);
});
```

and don't use `"pre code"` for the jQuery selector. Not sure if that's exactly how the plugin is used, but I would think that's what you need to change...

**EDIT:**

If you're not using jQuery, you may want to try something like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var allPre, i, j;
    allPre = document.getElementsByTagName("pre");
    for (i = 0, j = allPre.length; i < j; i++) {
        hljs.highlightBlock(allPre[i]);
    }
};
```

It needs to be in `window.onload` or something similar to make sure the DOM is ready for manipulation.

Comment: thank's for your answer, but where i must put your suggestion? i just use highlight js file not jQuery, i think your means is here `<script type="text/javascript">
hljs.tabReplace = '';
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
</script>` right or not?

Comment: did you read the user guide you provided? if you look at the custom initialization section, it tells you exactly what to do. calling hljs.highlightBlock(param) and passing a DOM element as "param" highlights individual sections instead of just finding the defaults (code tags in pre tags). so it's up to you to get the elements you want to highlight (all the pre's) and call highlightBlock on them

Comment: examples in user guide aren't so clear, i can't understand what to do! i am newbie in DOM! use of this code is simple but just for `<pre><code></code></pre>` but i don't no how make it to work for PRE!

Comment: did you see my edit in this answer? i updated it with i think is a solution for non-jQuery. let me know if that works

Answer (score 1):

One special, related circumstance, though which is too long for a comment:

Invocation upon the DOM completion event will not suffice on the new **blogger.com / blogspot Dynamic View Templates** and probably other similar sites, as in this case the DOM is actually loaded but merely consists out of an *injection-ready div element* and the DOM content is injected via a JavaScript method, which itself is called in a set-timeout:

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    blogger.ui().configure().view();
  }, 800);
```

In order for the syntaxhighlighting to work then, the complex DOM tree must be finished. One solution is through triggering `hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();` or the custom `highlightBlock` function after a generous timeout period.

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    blogger.ui().configure().view();
  setTimeout(function() {$('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});}, 2000);
  }, 800);
```

Answer (score 0):

select Any one prebuilt version of highlight.js with 22 commonly used languages is hosted by following CDNs:

```
cdnjs
==========

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>

jsdelivr
==========

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/highlight.js/9.9.0/styles/default.min.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/highlight.js/9.9.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

The bare minimum for using highlight.js on a web page is linking to the library along with one of the styles and calling initHighlightingOnLoad:

```
    <script>
         hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    </script>
```

This will find and highlight code inside of <pre><code> tags; it tries to detect the language automatically. If automatic detection doesn’t work for you, you can specify the language in the class attribute

```
    <pre>
    <code class="html">
        This is heading 1
    </code>
    </pre>
```

for more information refer this two links.
https://highlightjs.org/usage/
https://highlightjs.org/download/